# Why is my loop not working without a messagebox.show()?

Tags: loops

I want to have a windows form do a "lable countdown" at start, i have hade the same problem with other codes before, when im in a loop it does not execute until loop ends but when i put a messegebox in the loop it works perfectly...

### example:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        counter();
    }

private void counter()
    {
        for(int i = 3; i > 0; i--)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            MessageBox.Show(i.ToString());
            label2.Text = i.ToString();
        }
```

but when i take away the messegebox the program does not countdown is runs the code and displays the last char in this case 1.

Comment: have a look at the BackgroundWorker. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403%28v=vs.95%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The compiler concludes that there is no need to execute the entire loop since the final result will be 1 anyway. This is an example of [loop unrolling](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_unrolling).

Comment: I don't understand. What do you need to solve? The compiler solved it already, right? It just optimized it, but the finel result is 1, as you expected.

Comment: yes but can i force it to give me a lable change of 3... 2... 1... like it does with a messagebox inside the loop?

Comment: That's a different thing. You wouldn't get expected results even without compiler optimizations. I don't know which language this is (C# I assume), search for UI timers or similar for the language and library you are implementing this with.

Comment: C# it is... i tried to do a loop with keybord.iskeydown and got the same problem, iskeydown did not get the key press but when i put a messagebox inside loop it got the keypress...